# Unable to get Residuals for AOV in R

Tags: r, anova

I have a dataframe in R.

This is part of the head of the DF:

```
Sujet  T  E  O  P  meanTR

1      1  0  0  0  0.97
1      1  0  0  0  1.44
2      0  1  0  1  0.94
```

- Sujet : from 1 to 12
- T , E , O , P : 1 or 0
- meanTR : Numeric

I want to get the anova table, so I tried this:

```
model_all <- aov(meanTR ~ E*O*P+ Error(Sujet/E*O*P), data = df)
```

After that, I want to extract the residuals of my models to plot them

So I tried this :

`res <- residuals(model_all)` returns `NULL`

So I found people online suggesting this solution:

```
model_all.pr <- proj(model_all)      
res <- model_all.pr[[3]][, "Residuals"]
```

But this returns subscript out of bound

```
res <- model_all.pr[[3]]["Residuals"]
```

But this returns `NA`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm really confused

Any help would be appreciated.

The main goal is to be able to run this:

```
plot(res)

qqnorm(res)
```

Comment: Remove the comma before Residuals in your last one

Comment: @griffinevo it returns NA

Comment: Can you paste the output of `str(model_all.pr)`

Comment: @griffinevo it's a list with 13 elements

Comment: I guess you want to extract the residuals from the "Within" matrix: `model_all.pr[["Within"]][ , "Residuals"]`. In general it's safer to extract objects/variables by name instead of index (as done in the code you tried).

Comment: @Henrik that's what I was trying to get to by asking for the structure, I needed the output from you helpasisterout

Comment: Also @helpasisterout code to make the problem reproducible (ie `df <- data.frame("Sujet" = sample(1:12....`) would have been very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `aov()`, you'll get a top-level `$residuals` attribute for some fits but not others.

For example with a simple model like the following, you can access residuals directly (use `str()` to see the structure of an object, include what attributes can be accessed):

```
fit1 <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)

str(fit1$residuals)
## Named num [1:150] -0.644 -0.956 -1.111 -1.234 -0.722 ...
## - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

But in the more complex model specification you're using (i.e. with an explicit/custom error term), there are separate residual values in each of the top-level attributes:

```
fit2 <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Error(Species/Sepal.Length), data=iris)

fit2$residuals # NULL

names(fit2)
## [1] "(Intercept)"   "Species"   "Sepal.Length:Species"   "Within"

fit2$Species$residuals
## 2         3 
## -1.136219  5.179749 

str(fit2$Within$residuals)
## Named num [1:144] -1.83e-15 -2.49e-15 -1.90e-15 -2.55e-15 -2.89e-15 ...
## - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:144] "7" "8" "9" "10" ...
## ...
## ...
```

I haven't thought about the stats behind enough to say why this is, but I'm sure it is reasonable.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually it worked with : `fit2[['Within']][,'Residuals']` , but thank you.

Comment: yep, selects the same element but with different syntax :)